# javascript regexp that allows alphanumeric and dot (.)

Tags: javascript, php, regex

from `regexp=^(?:[a-zA-Z]+(?:[.'\-,])?\s?)+$`, how am I suppose to do it allowing only alphanumeric and dots? Thanks!

Comment: If you wrote that regexp, why can't you modify it? Your requirements seem much simpler than what you've already written.

Comment: because, I have tried those simple codes and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
regexp = ^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+$
```

Comment: This is also useful for testing: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Why is that when I entered `?` or `,`, it still allows it? It should only allow alphanumeric and dot.

Comment: Try using the square brackets (i updated the answer).

Answer (score 0):

This will get alphnum and dots..

```
   /[a-zA-Z0-9.]/
```

Comment: I used `"regexp=/[a-zA-Z0-9.]/"`, it still doesn't work. Even if I only entered letters.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript the regular expressions shouldn't be in quotes, but in slashes. For exapmple:

```
var myregexp = /[a-z0-9\.]+/i;
var myvar = "I am a regular expression.";
var result = myregexp.test(myvar);
```

returns true, because in `myvar` there are only digits, letters and dots.

> Note: the dots are special symbols and must be preceded by `\`

Comment: I'm using the `gen_validatorv4.js` javascript and just added the conditions in script in my php file